# How remove duplicate multidimensional array by first dimension

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

i have a 2-dimensionl array such as this:

```
  Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => talk
        [1] => amount
    )
    [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => base
        [1] => amazing
    )
    [2] => Array
    (
        [0] => talk
        [1] => filter
    )
    [3] => Array
    (
        [0] => label
        [1] => any
    )
    [4] => Array
    (
        [0] => talk
        [1] => amount
    )
    [5] => Array
    (
        [0] => tour
        [1] => any
    )
)
```

how **remove duplicate value by first dimension** and result such as this:

```
  Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => talk
        [1] => amount
    )
    [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => base
        [1] => amazing
    )
    [2] => Array
    (
        [0] => label
        [1] => any
    )
    [3] => Array
    (
        [0] => tour
        [1] => any
    )
)
```

there is much help about remove duplicate values in the array, but I didn't see any sample about remove duplicates by specific dimension.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307674/how-to-remove-duplicate-values-from-a-multi-dimensional-array-in-php

Comment: read this http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function uniqueArray($array)
{
  $result = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $array)));

  foreach ($result as $key => $value)
  {
    if ( is_array($value) )
    {
      $result[$key] = uniqueArray($value);
    }
  }

  return $result;
}
?>
```

*This will helps you*

**Note: not tested**

Comment: This doesn't just check the first element of the sub-arrays.